# jquery expander plugin custom "read-more" link

Tags: jquery, expander

I am using the [jQuery Expander plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) . It works well as expected. I have the expandText set as "read more". Is it possible to change the location where it appears? I don't want it to appear inline, along with the running text. Is it possible to put a anchor tag somewhere else in the page and associate the expand/collapse functionality to that anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there are any functions in the API for this plugin that allow you to do that.

You could always use CSS to reposition the `<span class='read-more'></span>` element wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the expander plugin is needed for that, just jQuery.

You can use jQuery's .hide and .show functions to show or hide any element in a similar way to the expander plugin.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9mUpe/

Comment: nope. The Expander plugin takes one piece of text and split it to teaser and a "read more" part. Also if it contains html tags it still works.